# Intersection of 2 linked lists using C

Tags: c, list, intersection

So the goal is to return a new linked list that is the intersection of the two lists a and b, that is the list of all the items that are common to the two lists. The items in the intersection are unique.

The code I have leads to a segmentation error, what is the problem?

```
SLList *
sllist_intersection(SLList *a, SLList *b) {
        SLEntry * e = b->head;
        SLList * list;
        list->head = NULL;
        SLEntry * f = a->head;
        while (e != NULL) {
                while (f != NULL) {
                        if (e->value == f->value) {
                                sllist_add_end(list, e->value);
                                break;
                        }
                        f = f->next;
               }
               e = e->next;
               f = a->head;
       }
       return list;
```

Here is the header file I forgot to include:

```
  2 struct SLEntry {
  3   int value;
  4   struct SLEntry * next;
  5 };
  6
  7 typedef struct SLEntry SLEntry;
  8
  9 struct SLList {
 10   SLEntry * head;
 11 };
 12
 13 typedef struct SLList SLList;
 14
 15 void sllist_init(SLList * list);
 16 void sllist_add_end( SLList *list, int value );
 17 int sllist_remove(SLList *list, int value);
 18 void sllist_remove_interval(SLList *list, int min, int max);
 19 SLList * sllist_intersection(SLList *a, SLList *b);
 20 void sllist_print(SLList *list);
```

Comment: What is the use of `SLEntry`?

Comment: `SLList * list;  list->head = NULL;` : `list` is uninitialize. `(Invalid pointer)->head = NULL`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is **Memory Allocation.**

1.Before doing `list->head=NULL` , Allocate some memory for `list`.
You can use `malloc here.`

```
SLList * list=malloc(sizeof(SLList));
```

No memory is allocated for the pointer so you cannot initialize its members.